# How to trim the characters in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list.

```
file_name = ['a.3903902.pdf','b.3432312.pdf','c.239002191.pdf','d.23423192010.pdf']
```

I want to trim the strings in the list to remove the characters including `.` sign and the numbers.

Expected output:

```
file_name = ['a.pdf','b.pdf','c.pdf','d.pdf']
```

Comment: The output includes a `.` sign

Comment: yes in the format. in the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex with pattern as `r'\.\d+'`. This will literally match `.` followed by one ore more digits.

```
>>> import re
>>> file_name = ['a.3903902.pdf','b.3432312.pdf','c.239002191.pdf','d.23423192010.pdf']
>>> [re.sub(r'\.\d+', '', f) for f in file_name]
['a.pdf', 'b.pdf', 'c.pdf', 'd.pdf']
```

Comment: This answer it better, since it uses regex in an efficient way (unlike `list.split` twice)

Answer (score 2):

```
def stripped(text):
    fn = text.split(".")
    return (fn[0]+"."+fn[len(fn)-1])

file_name = 
['a.3903902.pdf','b.3432312.pdf','c.239002191.pdf','d.23423192010.pdf']
output = []
for x in file_name:
    output.append(stripped(x))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_name = ['{}.{}'.format(x.split('.')[0], x.split('.')[2]) for x in file_name]
```